# how to implode multiple values?

Tags: php

How to implode multiple values?

I have following implode method:

```
$a = array("".$_POST['questionid']."","$qid");
$b = array("".$_POST['AnswerID']."","$ans");
$c = array("".$_POST['timetaken']."","$time");

$comma = implode(",",$a);
echo "$comma";
```

it gives:`1,2` and print a,b value

```
    $comma = implode(",",$a);
    echo "$comma";
    $comma1 = implode(",",$b);
    echo "$comma1";
```

it gives:`1,34,2` how do i print `1,2,3,4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you add `,` by your self to variable `$b`

Change from

```
$comma1 = implode(",",$b);
```

into

```
$b[0] = ",".$b[0];
$comma1 = implode(",",$b);
echo $comma1;
```

**2nd method**: -
Secondly you can marge arrays by using `array_merge()` then you can `implode` it via `,`

```
$comma = implode(",", array_merge($a, $b));
echo $comma;
```

Comment: thank's for your answer! but it's not working i got error:      `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 75

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 75
1,1`

Comment: @user5789755 I have updated my answer. I prefer you to use 2nd method.

Comment: ok it's working.how to insert into db these values separate columns like:`a` column a values `b` column `b` values

Comment: Its simple as you can do it like something `(a, b) VALUES ($a, $b)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_merge()` to first merge all arrays and then implode them. Like this :

```
$comma = implode(",", array_merge($a, $b));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge` for `$a` and `$b` it will give you **1,3,4,2** after implode for sequence use `sort()` function.

**Example:**

```
$a = array($_POST['questionid'],$qid);
$b = array($_POST['AnswerID'],$ans); 

// merge both
$merge = array_merge($a,$b);

// for ASC order
sort($merge);
$comma = implode(",",$merge); 
echo $comma; //1,2,3,4
```

**Issue in your code:**

You are not using comma between both `implode()` so you are getting 1,34,2.

Now if you need to print in sequence you need to use `sort();`